# Running JavaScript code every 15 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I've been trying to show a random quote in my webpage with jQuery. But the `while(true) { }` approach did not solve my problem, and yet when I searched a bit, I see that it is not recommended.

I have a JavaScript array containing some strings.

```
var quotes = new Array();
quotes[0] = "string 1";
quotes[1] = "string 2";
quotes[2] = "string 3";
quotes[3] = "string 4";
```

This code works well:

```
$(function() {
    var random_quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)]; 
    var $rand = $('div#randomQuote');
    $rand.append(random_quote);
    $rand.hide();
    $rand.fadeIn("500");
});
```

However, I'm trying to run this every 15 seconds to renew the quote.

As I said, I have tried a while true loop and sleep function but it didn't work.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval)

```
setInterval(yourFunction, timeInMilliseconds);
```

---

```
function randomQuote () {
    var random_quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)]; 
    var $rand = $('div#randomQuote');
    $rand.append(random_quote);
    $rand.hide();
    $rand.fadeIn("500");
}

$(function () {
    setInterval(randomQuote, 15000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var quotes = ["string 1", "string 2", "string 3", "string 4"];

$(function() {

    function doQuote() {
        var random_quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)]; 
        var $rand = $('div#randomQuote');
        $rand.append(random_quote);
        $rand.hide();
        $rand.fadeIn("500");
    }

    setInterval(function() { doQuote() }, 150000); 
});
```

Using the `new Array()` constructor is considered bad practice and defining an array literal is the preferred method.

Comment: Why are you using an anonymous function as the argument to `setInterval`?

Comment: Because it is best practice. Because setInterval works like eval() it is advised to use a function instead of a string. Read JavaScript the good parts ;)

Comment: I'll rephrase: Why are you creating a new function that does nothing but call an existing function with no arguments instead of just passing the existing function directly?

Comment: thanks, which jquery method should i use instead of append? since it keeps appending strings when i want to change them? (sorry total jquery newbie here :) )